# How to use RGBA16 in GLSL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to draw some king of depth map in GLSL, and I need at least one 10bit channel for that. I decided to use GL_R16 or GL_RGBA12 - they are the nearest one, and GL_R16 will cost less gpu memory (cose it will.. right?).

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA12, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

And here comes the problem: How to make GLSL use it properly? Sampler2D converts it to classic 8-bit RGBA...
What about the clamping? In GLSL every component color is normalized to [0,1] - is it the same for 16bit?
All I would like to know is just how to use it.

Comment: What GLSL `#version` are you targeting?

Comment: *"Sampler2D converts it to classic 8-bit RGBA"* - I'm pretty sure it doesn't. In the end what you get from `texture2D` is a `float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sampler2D converts it to classic 8-bit RGBA...

No, it doesn't. A `sampler2d` does not know or care about the format (unless it's an integer format, in which case you get undefined behavior). It converts it into a *float*; nothing more.

> What about the clamping?

Clamping is irrelevant, since GL_RGBA16 is an unsigned *normalized* format. The integer values on the range [0, 65535] are converted to [0, 1], just like GL_RGBA8 converts [0, 255] to [0, 1]. This is not "clamping"; this is what your format says for OpenGL to do. The higher precision formats only provide better *precision*; they don't provide larger numbers.

If you want to actually get 16-bit integers as *integers*, then you need to use a format that actually stores *integers*. GL_RGBA16UI stores 16-bit unsigned integers. Of course, that requires OpneGL 3.x+ hardware. And you have to use a `usampler2d`.

Comment: Well then... that's good news =] - but that means that my problem is somewhere else that in that format conversion... Anyways you gave me some very useful piece information here. Thank you for that. Unfortunately I use SDL 1.2, so I can't get higher then OGL 2. But what I can do is always "denormalization" back to [0, 65535] range ;) I won't be so efficient and precisional, but it seems to me, that I have my hands tied.